# Regular expression for web URL to also match the private hosts

Tags: javascript, java, regex, url, web

I have the following regex for matching the Web URL pattern, but it does not identify the private hosts such as http://localhost:8080 or http://internalhost.mydomain. How can this regex be modified to match that.

^((?:(http|https|Http|Https|HTTP|HTTPS)://(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\$-_.+!*\'()\,\;\?\&\=]|(?:\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,64}(?::(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\$-_.+!*\'()\,\;\?\&\=]|(?:\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,25})?\@)?)?((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,64}.)+(?:(?:aero|arpa|asia|a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz])|(?:biz|b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz])|(?:cat|com|coop|c[acdfghiklmnoruvxyz])|d[ejkmoz]|(?:edu|e[cegrstu])|f[ijkmor]|(?:gov|g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy])|h[kmnrtu]|(?:info|int|i[delmnoqrst])|(?:jobs|j[emop])|k[eghimnrwyz]|l[abcikrstuvy]|(?:mil|mobi|museum|m[acdghklmnopqrstuvwxyz])|(?:name|net|n[acefgilopruz])|(?:org|om)|(?:pro|p[aefghklmnrstwy])|qa|r[eouw]|s[abcdeghijklmnortuvyz]|(?:tel|travel|t[cdfghjklmnoprtvwz])|u[agkmsyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[etu]|z[amw]))|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]).(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0).(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0).(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])))(?::\d{1,5})?)$

Comment: This regex is wrong. I can see several errors instantly: `//` are not escaped and `.` is not escaped. It won't work the way you want it. Also, do you need that to work in Java or in Javascript?

Comment: See this answer for help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35996365/363573. Just my two cents...

Comment: @bezmax, I have not included escape chars intentionally to make it relatively read-able. In code, those are escaped. I am looking for Java

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider the following regexes from: "*Regular expression cookbook 2nd edition*" from O'reilly pages 448-450.

**For Java 7**:

```
\A
(# Scheme
 (?<scheme>[a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*):
 (# Authority & path
  //
  (?<user>[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=]+@)?              # User
  (?<host>[a-z0-9\-._~%]+                            # Named host
  |       \[[a-f0-9:.]+\]                            # IPv6 host
  |       \[v[a-f0-9][a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:]+\])  # IPvFuture host
  (?<port>:[0-9]+)?                                  # Port
  (?<hostpath>(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?)    # Path
 |# Path without authority
  (?<schemepath>/?[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+
                (/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?)?
 )
|# Relative URL (no scheme or authority)
 (?<relpath>
  # Relative path
  [a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=@]+(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?
 |# Absolute path
  (/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)+/?
 )
)
# Query
(?<query>\?[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?
# Fragment
(?<fragment>\#[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?
\Z
```

You'll need the free-spacing/comments (*x*) and the case insensitive (*i*) flags.

Tested on: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

[image]

**For javascript**:

```
^([a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*:(\/\/([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=]+@)?([a-z0-9\-._~%]+|\[[a-f0-9:.]+\]|\[v[a-f0-9][a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:]+\])(:[0-9]+)?(\/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*\/?|(\/?[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+(\/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*\/?)?)|([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=@]+(\/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*\/?|(\/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)+\/?))(\?[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@\/?]*)?(#[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@\/?]*)?$
```

You'll need the case insensitive flag (*i*).

**Test 1**: https://regex101.com/r/uQ5zD3/1

**Test 2**: https://regex101.com/r/gY3lA8/1

If it helped you, please consider purchasing this most excellent book (cookbook means that you can use the regex as they are and they will work right way) and don't forget to accept the answer.

Great success buddy

Answer (score 1):

Here is a description of your regex:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: What tool have you used to produce this?